# Why the training and error loss are similar?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, multiclass-classification, dropout

I am running a code to classify hand gestures. The code of the model is as follows:

```
model_d = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=X_train.shape[1:]),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=25, activation='relu', kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.GlorotNormal(seed=1)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=12, activation='relu',kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.GlorotNormal(seed=1)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=6, activation='softmax',kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.GlorotNormal(seed=1))
])

print(model_d.summary())
```

For compilation, I have written the following lines:

```
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001)
model_d.compile(optimizer=opt,
             loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

When I train the model using the following code:

```
history_d = model_d.fit(x=X_train, y=y_train, epochs=1500, batch_size=32, verbose=0)
plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))
plt.plot(history_d.history['loss'])
plt.plot
(history_d.history['accuracy'])
plt.legend(['Loss', 'Accuracy'])
plt.title('Loss and Accuracy Plot for Learning Rate 0.001', size=14, weight='bold')
plt.grid('major')
plt.grid('minor')
plt.show()
```

I am getting the following error and accuracy graph:

[image]

When I evaluate the model, using following lines of code:

```
print('The print accuracy is {:.3f}%'.format(model_d.evaluate(x=X_train, y=y_train, verbose=0)[1]*100))
print('The print accuracy is {:.3f}%'.format(model_d.evaluate(x=X_test, y=y_test, verbose=0)[1]*100))
```

I get the same accuracy for both training and testing data; that is, 16.667%.

**Please note that when I run the same code without using the dropout layer, I get 83% training, and 68% testing accuracy.** I am new in the field of deep learning; therefore, please pardon my ignorance.

Comment: the dropout works by setting to zero some weights of a tensor. You shouldn't put it after flatten, since in that case you are randomly changing some of your input values to 0.

Comment: 16.66% is 1/6, so your model is not doing anything useful. your question is not what you mentioned in topic. Please change your topic to be related to your problem (Dropout)

Comment: @EdoardoGuerriero Thank you for the message. I removed the dropout layer after the flatten layer, but my model still giving the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Dropout is used for generalization (or lowering the overfitting) but I guess your network is weak (it has just few layers and just a few neurons in each layer and your problem is a little hard for it to solve) so it should work hard and use all its capability to get a good result. In this situation *Dropout* turns 20% of the neurons off and makes it harder for the network to do what it want.

I'm not sure if this is the reason, so test it by increasing complexity (increase neurons count) and see if the network with dropout can get some good results or not (please let me know).

I suggest to use *Dropout* when your network is complex enough and you have overfitting.

Comment: Thank you for the message. I applied the dropout layers because the model was overfitting. As you can read in my questions that the training and testing accuracies were 83% and 68%, respectively.

Comment: @Winter2019 Sorry, I didn't pay attention to that. If the dataset is on internet, can you give me a link to it so I can play with it and maybe find the answer?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. The data (train_signs.h5 and test_signs.h5) at https://github.com/JudasDie/deeplearning.ai/tree/master/Improving%20Deep%20Neural%20Networks/Week3/datasets. Please let me know if you find any solution.

Comment: @Winter2019 sorry but I didn't work with *.h5* as dataset before (from what I know it is a format to save keras model but I don't know how to work with it as dataset).